# Add button to bundle options in adminhtml with UI components

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent, bundle

I seem to be unable to add a button to the bundle options in the product edit screen in the backend.

The goal ist to have a button before or after the option title (position is not really important).

I have tried to add a new button to this form using ui-components in XML and PHP. Here is my code:

**XML**

*File:*

```
app/code/[Vendor]/[Namespace]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/bundle_product_listing.xml
```

*Code:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="my_button" xsi:type="string">[Vendor]\[Namespace]\Block\Path\To\My\Button\Class</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </listingToolbar>
    </listing>
```

*Result:*
Nothing happens

**PHP**

*File:*

```
app/code/[Vendor]/[Namespace]/Plugin/Bundle/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier.php
```

*Code:*

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Namespace\Plugin\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Form;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Control\Button;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;

class BundlePanelPlugin
{

    public function afterModifyMeta(\Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\BundlePanel $model, $result)
    {
        $result['bundle-items']['children']['bundle_options']['children']['record']['children']['product_bundle_container']['children']['option_info']['children']['copy_button']['arguments']['data']['config'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button',
            'title' => __('Do something please'),
            'label' => __('Do something please'),
            'sortOrder' => 1,
            'on_click' => 'alert("yep")',
            'formElement' => Container::NAME,
            'componentType' => Container::NAME,
            'provider' => null

        ];
        return $result;
    }
}
```

*Result:*

My plugin gets executed and adds the button to the page. However, it leads to a Javascript error saying `knockout.js:3012 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return $data.label }"`.
I also tried to add 'actions' to the button, but that just led to another error.

Thanks for your time & help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it done. Seems my mistake was that I tried to add to the `option_info` node, when I needed to add it one node higher. I also needed to wrap the button inside a container (not sure if this is required though).

Here is my modified PHP function:

```
public function afterModifyMeta(BundlePanel $model, $result)
    {
        $result['bundle-items']['children']['bundle_options']['children']['record']['children']['product_bundle_container']['children']['copy_button'] = [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => '',
                        'sortOrder' => 10,
                        'collapsible' => true,
                        'componentType' => Container::NAME
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'children' => [
                'copy_button_button' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'formElement' => 'button',
                                'componentType' => 'button',
                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button',
                                'visible' => true,
                                'title' => __('Copy Bundle-Option'),
                                'actions' => [
                                    [
                                        'targetName' => '${ $.parentName.replace(".copy_button", ".bundle_selections") }',
                                        'actionName' => 'processingCopyOption'
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

        return $result;
}
```

Comment: Where is your block class 
[Vendor]\[Namespace]\Block\Path\To\My\Button\Class?